# AngularJS ng-click is working only once in modal

Tags: modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-click

I'm using the [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) jQuery plugin to create a modal and I have some links on it that have ng-click="setId(11)".

The problem is that it's working just once. After the first click the function setId isn't called anymore. The modal opens but the links and ng-click don't do anything.

Modal:

```
<div id="basic-modal-content">
    <a href ng-click="setId(11)" class="simplemodal-close">11</a>
    <a href ng-click="setId(16)" class="simplemodal-close">16</a>
    ...
</div>
```

app.js:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.origin = 'none';

    $scope.setId = function(id) {
        $scope.origin = id;
    };
    ...
```

Reading some posts it seems to be a scope problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem when you are modifying a variable, which is a direct attribute of the $scope. Could you please try do replace `$scope.origin` by e.g. `$scope.options.origin`?

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = {};
    $scope.options.origin = 'none';

    $scope.setId = function(id) {
        $scope.options.origin = id;
    };
...
```

Comment: Hi @AlexanderBondar, I tried your approach but it does'n work. The ng-click inside the model still works only the first time. What can it be?

Comment: It seems like the `close` function of the plugin replaces the contents of your element (`#basic-modal-content`). So the replaced elements disappear as well as the Angular bindings.

Comment: You know any angularJS modal I can use to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap, its modal works pretty fine with Angular.

Comment: I'm not using Bootstrap, but I'll see the possibility to use it.
Thank you for all your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me when the flag value I toggle when showing/ hiding the modal dialogue has the same name as the function name that toggles this flag value

```
$scope.showPopup = function(){
    $scope.showPopup=true;
}
```

Resolution is to rename either the flag or the function.